# how to target a Custom Content Query Web Part order columns

Tags: content-query-web-part, picture-library

I just made a custom CQWP and I am loading a PICTURE LIBRARY into the CQWP. I will like to target the first item in my picture library like this

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($SafeImageUrl) != 0">

</xsl:if>
```

My question is how do I target this, is there a a variable to do something like the pseudocode below

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($OrderId) == 'first'">

</xsl:if>
```

Edit: I found out that I can use the Created column to target the first item, now the question is how do I do this in my ItemStyle.xsl.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below rule to check that

```
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)= 0">
    <!-- First Item = Apply your style -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I tried it this but caused an error                

    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
     <div class="content" style="bottom:0">
      <div class="home-featured">
         <p class="intro">A DESCRIPIVE TEXT</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>